# Property won't insert properly in Sequelize Model Create

Tags: postgresql, express, sequelize.js

I want to insert username, password, and role. But when I executed my function, the role property won't be executed.

This is my migration file:

```
            id: {
                allowNull: false,
                autoIncrement: true,
                primaryKey: true,
                type: Sequelize.INTEGER
            },
            username: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                unique: true,
            },
            password: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            role: {
                type: Sequelize.STRING,
                allowNull: false,
            },
            createdAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            },
            updatedAt: {
                allowNull: false,
                type: Sequelize.DATE
            }
```

And this is my function for inserting new data (usermodel.js)

```
        static register = ({ username, password }) => {
            const encryptedPassword = this.encrypt(password);
            return this.create({ username, password: encryptedPassword, role: 'user' })
        }
```

This is what I got when I executed the function:

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO "UserModel" ("id","username","password","createdAt","updatedAt") VALUES (DEFAULT,$1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "id","username","password","createdAt","updatedAt";
```

Is there anything that I do wrong? Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, the problem is within the model. I haven't defined the role in the model init. I solved it by adding the role in model:

```
UserModel.init({
        username: DataTypes.STRING,
        password: DataTypes.STRING,
        role: DataTypes.STRING
    }
```